# Sharepoint Deploy new Column to list

Tags: list, deployment, sharepoint-2010

I'm fairly new to SharePoint 2010, I've had some experience with 2007 but only debugging and fixing some small bug.

Assuming that i create a new solution for SP 2010 in VS2010 and i add a feature to create some list definitions and also some list instances of those list definition templates. These are all declared through Schema.xml =>

I deploy successfully and add a few items to my new lists.

Now i want to add a few extra columns (fields) to my lists, how will i deploy them?

I don't want to create them in code, i would like to have a up to date solution that with every new developer a simple deployment would create an up and running Dev environment.

What is the correct way to do the deployment in this case?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the schema.xml file defined for the list, then you really want to add your new columns using the  collection within the list definition.  You also want to be sure your list is defined by a content type, allowing for reuse.  So within your schema.xml file, it would look something like this:

```
<List xmlns:ows="Microsoft SharePoint" Title="Test List" FolderCreation="FALSE" Direction="$Resources:Direction;" Url="Lists/Test-List" BaseType="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <MetaData>
    <ContentTypes>
      <ContentType ID="0x010068a2e063a1a74913a37ecdb61ab2c721" Name="Test" Group="Custom Content Types" Description="Test Description" Inherits="TRUE" Version="0">
        <FieldRefs>
          <FieldRef ID="{c2f80e7d-666e-4273-8b58-d5c8a13a9d6a}" Name="Col1" ShowInNewForm="TRUE" Required="TRUE" ShowInEditForm="TRUE"/>
          <FieldRef ID="{a84d620a-d42d-455c-8ef8-7e9f1d443250}" Name="Col2" Required="TRUE" ShowInNewForm="TRUE" ShowInEditForm="TRUE"/>
          <!-- Your new field refs here here -->
        </FieldRefs>
      </ContentType>
    </ContentTypes>
    <Fields>
      <Field ID="{c2f80e7d-666e-4273-8b58-d5c8a13a9d6a}" Type="Text" AllowDeletion="FALSE" Description="Key" AllowDuplicateValues="FALSE" EnforceUniqueValues="TRUE" Indexed="TRUE" Name="Col1" DisplayName="Col1" Group="Custom Columns" />
      <Field ID="{a84d620a-d42d-455c-8ef8-7e9f1d443250}" Type="Text" AllowDeletion="FALSE" Name="Col2" DisplayName="Col2" Group="Custom Columns" />
      <!-- Your new fields here -->
    </Fields>
    ...
  </MetaData>
</List>
```

Don't forget to change your View as well!

Comment: Hi, Sorry for late response, connection down. Given your solution when I'll be adding new columns and deploy solution will the new columns get added preserving the current data?